# Como transferir os dados de uma tabela para outra em servidores diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql, linked-server

Preciso copiar os registros de uma tabela que está em um linked server MySQL para o SQL Server, ou seja, transferir os registros de um servidor para o outro. Alguém poderia me indicar uma maneira de executar isso através de uma *query*?

Comment: linked server entre `mysql` e `sql-server`?

Comment: Sim, são dois servidores e um usa mysql e o que eu estou usa sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `mysql` para o `sql-server` você pode fazer assim:

```
UPDATE tabela SET campo=A.campo FROM
(SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(nome-linked-server,'Select * From tabela')) A
  INNER JOIN join tabela B on b.Id=a.Id
```

Você deve informar o nome do link na função [OPENQUERY](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), e fazer os joins. No exemplo usei o alias "A".

Comment: Na verdade eu queria um insert, me expressei de forma errada na pergunta, desculpe. Mas o link que você enviou do OPENQUERY me ajudou. Obrigado Ricardo Pontual!

Comment: Entendi, só altear o update para um insert: `INSERT INTO tabela (campos) SELECT mesmos-campos FROM OPENQUERY(...)`